# Is it posssible to preinstall the files downloaded by graalvm nativeCompile to avoid using internet on build Spring (native) Boot 3?

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm

```
Error downloading component catalog from https://www.graalvm.org/component-catalog/v2/graal-updater-component-catalog-java17.properties: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
```

Is there a way to preinstall this file to avoid using Internet in build ?

Comment: A bit of context: this error comes from a tool called `gu` (Graalvm Updater) that tries to install some component (`gu install <component name>`). A workaround would be to download the component beforehand (it's a jar file) and invoke `gu install -L <component>.jar`

Comment: The graal-updater-component-catalog-java17.properties is a jar ? I do not understand which jar to install

Comment: On a computer with Internet access, run `gu info native-image`, it will print URL of the installable jar for the `native-image` component (I presume this is the component it tries to install. For complete list of available components, run `gu available`)